# Delete files with similar content length

Tags: bash

I have 20,000 photos, half of those photos are duplicates, how can I delete
Meaning
How can I delete pictures that contain duplicate content

Comment: are you talking about exact-byte-by-byte duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the duplicate by the file size, but by the byte

Comment: Here's the idea: the key point is to do an hash (eg: `sha256sum`) of each file contents and then work on sorting the hashes to find duplicates, which is way faster than sorting the files' content directly. Some tools might already do part of this (eg: [`duff`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/duff))

Comment: thank you my friend
You have deleted the duplicate files file
using
`duff -re . | xargs rm -r`
Ref [link](https://kaspars.net/blog/how-to-remove-duplicate-files-and-images-with-duff-in-linux)

Comment: Nice, duff appears to be made for this. I saw the command but never used it. You should post this as an answer to your own question. But don't use -r on rm, it's not needed and dangerous: use `--` instead. You'd probably have to rework the xargs command for extra safety unless you are sure there are no spaces in your file names.

Comment: It sounds like a good reminder
Thank you

Comment: There are literally hundreds of similar questions on this site. [Look for `fdupes` for instance](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+fdupes&ia=web).

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
duff -re . | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

The Commando prints duplicate files only `duff -re .`

Xargs takes data from stdin
It executes the command supplied as an argument to `rm`

ref
[link](https://kaspars.net/blog/how-to-remove-duplicate-files-and-images-with-duff-in-linux)

Thank ***A.B***

Comment: I really meant `--` not `--r` (which will be taken as a non-existing file anyway) . You don't want rm to be recursive, duff was already recursive

Comment: I have modified it. Seems I have read it incorrectly above

Comment: Can probably work because duff was called with `.`. Else `--` that you still didn't put would be needed for safety.